# making a persistent bootstrap datepicker

Tags: datepicker, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use one of these:
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

However, I'd like it to be the main element, i.e. always be displayed, not hide when clicked away from, and not display the element it writes to. I can't find any documentation or examples on how to do this. Any ideas?

I'd like to use this datepicker if at all possible because it's what I use in other areas of the site (where a non-persistent picker is needed) and would like to keep things consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <input type="text" name="startdate" id="date" />
 <div class="date" data-altfield="#date"></div>


 $(function(){
     $('.date').each(function(i,e){
         var $d = $(this);
         $d.datepicker({
            altField: $d.data('altfield')
        });
     });
 });
```

check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/MDTXS/2/

Comment: I like this approach, but I need it to work with the normal behavior elsewhere. I suppose I can get my hands dirty and actually write a full-fledged patch to the thing, if necessary...

Comment: after looking more closely at the code, it seems like this is the only possible approach. Thanks for pointing me to the right parts in the code!